# Android - Memory Leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

Based on below picture and the fact that the number of objects constantly grows over time. Is it safe to say that there is a memory leak in my code?

Also, how would I go about debugging it?

[image]

Comment: follow your code and see the memory consuming and when it release, there is missing details in your question

Comment: @Proxytype Thank you! Im just not very experienced with this. How can I see when memory is released by following my code?

Comment: you can use the profiling in android studio, start debug the application and follow the memory, try to find where you consuming it, and when you suppose to release it...

Answer (score 0):

First you can use Memory Monitor to watch the memory change,according to [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html).
Second you can run the app and click the "cause GC" button to gc,if the allocated heap size is growing more and more,then you can try MAT like [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to check is activity or fragment memory leak, use this code in your Application onCreate.

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .penaltyDialog()
    .build());
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
```